# Is there a better way to write a game flow in Java?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I want to write a backend for a game. In this game there are tasks that have to be fulfilled.
For example: Find a key for door x.
The number of tasks is unlimited, but will (probably) not exceed 25.

If a key is found as in the example above, it should be possible to solve tasks that are linked together.

My first attempt:
Task.java

```
public class Task {
private int id;
private boolean solved;
private Task[] links;
private String name;

public Task(int id, String name, Task... links) {
    this.id = id;
    this.links = links;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Everytime the command comes to solve a Task, all linked tasks will be checked if they're solved.
Also in Task.java:

```
public boolean solve() {
    if (this.links != null && links.length != 0) {
        for (Task t : links) {
            if (t.isSolved()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        this.solved = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This seems to be very inefficient and I would find it very difficult to watch out for all Task statuses. Is there a better way?

Comment: You should read a bit about premature optimization. Checking 25 objects is nothing unless you want to do that millions of time a second. Which you shouldn't do. In general, don't optimize before you see some performance issues.

Comment: To expand on what @Amongalen said: if there are roughly 25 tasks, then `Task.solve()` will be executed *at most* 25 times in a single playthrough (assuming a task doesn't get solved twice). This means that performance is almost entirely irrelevant in this case.

Comment: The tricky bit is that this backend will run on a Raspberry Pi (3b) and the Executionspeed is quite a limiting factor here (though you are right, checking 25 objects even per second isn't the limit of the Raspberry Pi). But the other problem is, that the Frontend will continue to ask if the task is solved to display the "followup tasks". Thank you @Amongalen for the pointout on premature optimization. I think I'll give it a shot and see what I can achieve. I'd like to accept this as an answer to the question if thats okay for you Joachim Sauer

Comment: Also you can agree ina  protocol  with the front end so it dont need to check if the tasks are solved in the backend if they already know that

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos could you go a little more into detail with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amongalen commented, there is no significant performance impact in checking 25 Tasks.